# How to get a url substring from a string in objective-c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa, parsing

```
&lt;p>&lt;a href="http://vimeo.com/23486376" title="Rebecca Black's Friday on Rock Band">&lt;img src="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/152/946/152946954_200.jpg" alt="Rebecca Black's Friday on Rock Band" />&lt;/a>&lt;/p>&lt;p>&lt;/p>&lt;p>Cast: &lt;a href="http://vimeo.com/thenerdery" style="color: #2786c2; text-decoration: none;">The Nerdery&lt;/a>&lt;/p>
```

I got a string like above, I am wondering what's the best way in objective-c to get the "http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/152/946/152946954_200.jpg" substring? NSScanner? NSString methods? Thanks!

update: the string is actually:

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href=&quot;http://vimeo.com/23333305&quot; title=&quot;Ad League Bowling Championship&quot;&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/151/787/151787049_200.jpg&quot; alt=&quot;Ad League Bowling Championship&quot; /&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;p&gt;Cast: &lt;a href=&quot;http://vimeo.com/thenerdery&quot; style=&quot;color: #2786c2; text-decoration: none;&quot;&gt;The Nerdery&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's another approach:

- Transform the string into actual HTML.  In other words, conver the `&lt;` and `&gt;` stuff into `<` and `>`
- Run it through an `NSXMLParser`
- In the [parser delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html), check the attributes dictionary passed into the [`-parser:didStartElement:namespaceURI:qualifiedName:attributes:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSXMLParserDelegate/parser%3adidStartElement%3anamespaceURI%3aqualifiedName%3aattributes%3a) method.
- If the element name is `@"img"`, then the `attributes` dictionary should have a key called `@"src"` that maps to the string `@"http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/152/946/152946954_200.jpg"`.
- Once you have the string, it's trivial to transform it into an `NSURL` using `+[NSURL URLWithString:]`

This will work regardless of how the source HTML changes over time.  The other approaches suggested are extremely fragile, because they rely on things like `src` being all lowercase and there only being a single `src` attribute anywhere in the string (what if you have 2?).  You don't want to parse HTML; you want to get an attribute out of an XML element.  So use the built-in way of doing it! :)

Comment: Looks like that's THE way to do it. But I used my quick and dirty way in the end though. Thanks for the great answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *strComplete = @"&lt;p>&lt;a href="http://vimeo.com/23486376" title="Rebecca Black's Friday on Rock Band">&lt;img src="http://b.vimeocdn.com/ts/152/946/152946954_200.jpg" alt="Rebecca Black's Friday on Rock Band" />&lt;/a>&lt;/p>&lt;p>&lt;/p>&lt;p>Cast: &lt;a href="http://vimeo.com/thenerdery" style="color: #2786c2; text-decoration: none;">The Nerdery&lt;/a>&lt;/p>";   
NSArray *arrComplete = [strComplete componentSeparatedBy:@"src="]; 
NSString *strSecond = [arrComplete objectAtIndex:1];  
NSArray *arrSecond = [strSecond componentSeparatedBy:@" alt"];  
NSString *strURLImage = [arrSecond objectAtIndex:0];
```

**strURLImage** will be your desired string.

Comment: this makes more sense to me and might be more efficient than my solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a framework for URL detection and parsing, such as [AutoHyperlinks](http://hg.cloggedtubes.com/autohyperlinks2/src/default). On iOS, you will, of course, have to build it statically or build the source directly into your app.

Alternatively, for iOS only (currently), use [NSDataDetector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/). Data detectors can find URLs, physical addresses, phone numbers, etc.; you tell it what you'll want from the string, then use [the methods of NSRegularExpression](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/) to obtain its findings.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming complete string is called myString, you can do:

```
NSRange srcRange = [myString rangeOfString:@"src="];
NSRange endrange = [myString rangeOfString:@"\"" options:nil range:
   NSMakeRange(srcRange.location + 5, [mystring count] - srcRange.location - 6)];
NSString *url = [myString subStringWithRange:
   NSMakeRange(srcRange.location + 5, srcRange.location + 5 + endRange.lenght)];
```

I haven't tested that so I could have put a +5 instead of a +6, so if the string has got some chars less or more than you want, just change the **numbers** in the last line.

Comment: I figured I would use this instead in the end: `        NSString *imgString = [[NSString alloc] init];
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:descriptionString];
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"img src=&quot;" intoString:nil];
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"http" intoString:nil];
        [scanner scanUpToString:@"&quot; alt" intoString:&imgString];` Thanks anyway.

Comment: Very happy if you found a solution yourself